# (iOS) Firebase: How to query and get an object if a property is between two Unix-timestamps?

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have an object called WashOrder that holds a property called "orderEndDateInUnix". I'd like to fetch all the WashOrders where the "orderEndDateInUnix" is within todays date and todays daye + one week.

```
static func getAllWashOrdersWithSubscriptionsEndingSoon(completionWithOrders: @escaping ([Order]) -> Void) {

        let databaseRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference()

        let date = Date()

        let oneWeekForward = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: 7, to: date)

        guard let weekForwardFromNowUnix = oneWeekForward?.timeIntervalSince1970 else { return }

        databaseRef.child("WashOrder")
            .queryOrdered(byChild: "orderEndDateInUnix")
            .queryStarting(atValue: date.timeIntervalSince1970)
            .queryEnding(atValue: weekForwardFromNowUnix)
            .observe(.childAdded, with: { (snap) in

                //Do stuff

        })
```

[image]

[image]

I've learned that I need to index the "orderEndDateInUnix"-property inside Firebase, which I've done. It still doesn't work though.

Why doesn't this work?

Comment: You've included a picture of the JSON tree in your question. Please replace that with the actual JSON as text, which you can easily get by clicking the Export JSON link in [your Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data/). Having the JSON as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do.